# grid lines on bar chart V3 chart js

Tags: grid, chart.js, bar-chart, line

Need gridlines on the bar chart , chart js  V3.

I tried many grid options nothing seems to be working , by default the grid lines seems to be going next to the bar chart and not on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
I finally figured it out , I'm gonna leave .


 let options = {
            plugins: { 
                  scales: {
                          x: {
                              offset: true,
                              grid: {
                                   offset: false
                                     }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }
```